# FastAPI: Return response with an array of objects

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

I'm currently working on a API that returns scraped data. The data is stored as an array but when I go return that array as a response on an endpoint, I get the following error:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for InnerObject
response
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
```

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
class InnerObject(BaseModel):
    foo: str

class OuterObject(BaseModel):
    bar: List[InnerObject]

@app.get("/test_single", response_model=InnerObject)
def test():
    return InnerObject(foo="Hello Mars")

@app.get("/test_multiple", response_model=OuterObject)
def test():
    objects = [InnerObject]

    objects.append(InnerObject(foo="Hello Earth"))
    objects.append(InnerObject(foo="Hello Mars"))

    return objects
```

I have an array of objects that I want to return as a response. It's also possible that I don't need outer/inner models but I have also attempted this and set the response_model to be `response_model=List[InnerObject]`. Returning a single `InnerObject` as seen in the `"/test_single"` endpoint works fine, so I assume it's to do with trying to return a [InnerObject]

Thanks for any responses in advance

### Solution

Thanks kosciej16, the problem was that I was adding the object name when declaring the list. So I was going `objects = [InnerObject]` when I should have been going `objects = []`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally fastapi tries to create `OuterObject` from thing you return.

In such case you have few options.

1. Create object explicitly

```
@app.get("/test_multiple", response_model=OuterObject)
def test():
    objects = []

    objects.append(InnerObject(foo="Hello Earth"))
    objects.append(InnerObject(foo="Hello Mars"))

    return OuterObject(bar=objects)
```

2. Change response_model

```
@app.get("/test_multiple", response_model=List[InnerObject])
def test():
    objects = []

    objects.append(InnerObject(foo="Hello Earth"))
    objects.append(InnerObject(foo="Hello Mars"))

    return objects
```

3. Change definition of `OuterObject`

```
class OuterObject(List[InnerObject]):
    pass
```